# Naked domain redirect with Heroku and GoDaddy

Tags: url, redirect, heroku, dns

I have an app hosted on heroku, and a domain name from GoDaddy. I've correctly set up forwarding so that if you go to www.mysitename.com, it goes to my Heroku app. However, I'm trying to configure it so if you type in mysitename.com, it still redirects to the Heroku app-- right now, it just brings me to a blank page when I do this (no error messages)

In my domain settings in GoDaddy, I set up forwarding with masking for both my domain (www.mysitename.com) and my subdomain (mysitename.com). Do I need to configure my DNS some way on GoDaddy? Or is it still not working just because it takes a long time to propogate? I've read some conflicting things from various places and haven't really found a straight forward answer. Would really appreciate some advice!

Answer (score 2):

In order to have traffic from your root domain forwarded to Heroku, your DNS provider needs to support CNAME flattening, which GoDaddy doesn't.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain

I solved this problem by signing up for a free CloudFlare Web account and then configuring my registrar to use CloudFlare to manage the DNS. You'll just go into GoDaddy, change your Nameserver to the values given to you by CloudFlare, and then you can manage your DNS on CloudFlare, which supports CNAME flattening. As a bonus the DNS (and other) services from CloudFlare are top notch and lightning fast.

Answer (score 1):

Look at adding a wildcard domain.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-wildcard-domain

Comment: OK, I tried that, and added in GoDaddy a CNAME record where the host is * and it points to the name of my heroku app....so far that hasn't changed anything, though..

Comment: Have you checked propagation using a tool like this? http://viewdns.info/propagation/

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about this. I just checked it and it looks like it just hasn't propagated yet. Thank you!